# WPUT how to skip the previous folders

Tags: linux, file-upload, command-line

I want to upload a file on a ftp with the wput command like this :

```
wput −−basename='/var/www/myproject/' /var/www/myproject/export/ ftp://user:password@ftp.mydomain.com/www/
```

I want to skip `/var/www/myproject` to get only `/export/` that is why I use `--basename`.

But I have an error on basename :

```
Error: File `−−basename=/var/www/myproject' does not exist. Don't know what to do about this URL.
```

I don't understand why because my script is executed and the project is uploaded. But he is uploaded in `/var/www/myproject/export/` on the other server and I want to upload the files in /export/.

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad... I failed the -- !

there is a bad char in the [wput doc](http://wput.sourceforge.net/wput.1.html) on the -- if you copy / paste.

Answer (score 0):

also after fiddling around a bit I think

```
wput −−basename=/var/www/myproject/ export/ ftp://user:password@ftp.mydomain.com/www/
```

is the correct syntax, i.e. once you've specified the basename you don't repeat it in the filename to uplaod.

JS